# Read a file and manipulate it with rhino JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, scripting, rhino

hope you are doing well, and feeling safe!

Can anyone help me to solve this issue, I am trying to read a file and manipulate it from JavaScript file ,this one is instantiated in an html code.

I succeeded to run the JavaScript code separately in rhino environment, but I did not when running it through html file in Firefox/chrome.

this is the JavaScript code:

```
const paragraph = readFile('file_name');
const found = String(paragraph.match(/set red_range.*/g));
const found_1 = String(paragraph.match(/set orange_range.*/g));


$(document).ready(function(){ 

var mc = {

red    : '',
 orange : '',
 orange : ''


};

function between(x, min, max) {
return x >= min && x <= max;

}


mc.red = found.split(' ')[2]
mc.orange = found_1.split(' ')[2]

var dc;
var first;
var second; 
var th;
 

$('p').each(function(index){


th = $(this);

dc = parseInt($(this).attr('data-color'),10);
  
  $.each(mc, function(value, name){
           
    first = parseInt(name.split('/')[0],10);
    second = parseInt(name.split('/')[1],10);
    
    console.log(between(dc, first, second));
    
    if( between(dc, first, second) ){
      th.addClass(value);
    }
  });

 });
});
```

Thanks in advance !

Comment: What do you mean by  "but I did not when running it through html file" ? Do you mean you tried to run it in a browser? If so, what browser? Remember that browsers do not expose the user's filesystem to webpage scripts for what should be obvious reasons to you.

Comment: yes I tried to run it in a Firefox but can't get anything

Comment: So you're asking why something which is **designed to not work** is not working then?

Comment: Why ?? can you explain more please ? I am beginner in JavaScript

Comment: @Dai, is there any alternative solution can do the job please ??

Answer (score 0):

> Can anyone help me to solve this issue, I am trying to read a file and manipulate it from JavaScript file ,this one is instantiated in an html code.

> I succeeded to run the JavaScript code separately in rhino environment, but I did not when running it through html file in Firefox.

> Why ?? can you explain more please ? I am beginner in JavaScript

- JavaScript (formally: ECMASCript) is a *general-purpose* scripting language.
- A *scripting language* is a vague technical term, but the term is generally understood to mean any language that runs within the context of a *host environment* which exposes externally-defined and [domain-specific](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/domain-specific) actors/objects into the script to be manipulated by the script.

So because ECMAScript is *general purpose* you can see it used in many circumstances, such as in web-pages for web-browsers, but it can also be used in [server-side code](https://expressjs.com/) ([since 1999](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JScript)), [the Windows desktop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/wscript), [Adobe Acrobat](https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/using/applying-actions-scripts-pdfs.html#about_javascript_in_acrobat), and others. Each of these represents a radically different *host environment*. For example, commands for manipulating the HTML DOM (such as `document.createElement`) will be present in a web-browser's JavaScript environment, but not the Adobe Acrobat environment.

With that out of the way, I hope you now understand that **within the context of JavaScript running within Rhino**, the script *does* have access to the user's local filesystem via Rhino's `readFile` function.

Whereas in a web-browser, JavaScript does not have automatic access to the user's filesystem **and there is no `readFile` function!**. While there is a non-standard FileSystem API - and that scripts can access files the user has selected with an `<input type="file">` - scripts cannot read arbitrary files off disk without any user-oversight.